# DOCKER: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /tmp/resnet

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I was following this [median article](https://medium.com/tensorflow/serving-ml-quickly-with-tensorflow-serving-and-docker-7df7094aa008) on serving resnet with tensorflow serving and docker. I followed all instructions perfectly but am getting this error :

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /tmp/resnet.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
```

While trying to run :

```
docker run -p 8501:8501 --name tfserving_resnet \
--mount type=bind,source=/tmp/resnet,target=/models/resnet \
-e MODEL_NAME=resnet -t tensorflow/serving &
```

What am I doing wrong...? I am simply copying and pasting commands! This is the first time I am using docker.

Comment: Does the `/tmp/resnet` directory exist in your host?

Comment: Yes it does... I followed all the instructions above the one giving this error... ls \tmp\resnet works..

Comment: Also I tried the exact same thing in ubuntu and it works fine... why does this problem occur in windows?

Comment: Shouldn't you pass your source location in the way Windows do? I mean, what does `/` mean in Windows? Try something like `d:/tmp/resnet`? (or even trying backslashes?)

Comment: Yes I had tried this for different model that I was working on:

 docker run -p 8501:9000 \
--mount type=bind,\
source=D:\Fight-Detection\deeplab_v3\serving\versions\deepnet,\
target=/models/deepnet \
-e MODEL_NAME=deepnet -t tensorflow/serving &